# Install Diagnostics messages on WinCE

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

I've a Windows CE device on which I try to install all Exceptions message contained in the NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab

My problem is, when double-clicking on the CAB File, I get the following error message :

> The file "NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab" is not a valid Windows CE Setup file.

As anyone faced this message? How can I fix it and install this CAB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you attempting to install this on a generic Windows CE (i.e. not WinMo/WEH) device?  If so that could very well be the problem.  Note that your CAB file has "wm" in in, indicating a Windows Mobile CAB.

Instead, try the non WinMo version `NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab` (found on my machine at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics`).

Comment: Yes I install on a generic WinCE device. I've seen the ".wm." but I've read that this CAB is the one to use. Other one is very big (800ko) and I've not enough space to install it...

Comment: I spoked to fast, used the other one and is OK. Thanks CF.NET Master :-)